# IBM Cloud functions using API key and not Bearer token?

Tags: function, authentication, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

It seems that when you create an IBM cloud function the default authentication is via the usage of auth tokens.  How could you setup your function to use an API key instead?
This would make it easier to use as an external integration for Watson Assistant.

I tried: `curl -X POST -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'apikey: xxxx'`

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-iamtoken_from_apikey and/or https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-iamapikeysforservices might be what you need

Comment: Yes I can generate an IAM token from an API key but it is only valid for a maximum of 60mn.  This would not work for Watson Assistant integration that seems to require a static IAM token (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to this section in the IBM Cloud Functions docs about [securing web actions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-actions_web#actions_web_secure). It shows how a special header, X-Require-Whisk-Auth, is passed to allow authentication with a secret. It is either randomly generated or set by you.

What you can implement in your action, in addition to what is offered by Functions, is to have an additional parameter. This could be "your" API key to check and could even identify different users.

Comment: The action was created from the function dashboard: https://cloud.ibm.com/functions.  This defines two endpoints when I enable as Web Action.  I get an HTTP endpoint and a REST API endpoint.  What you are telling me is that to change the authentication of the Web Action, I need to use the CLI.  For the REST API, not sure what I can do.  I seem to be stuck with IAM tokens, This is very confusing.

Comment: AFAIK It works with the dashboard, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your curl command is wrong. For apikeys, use the auto-generated command line (it's somehow hidden)

1. Select your function from the dashboard
2. Go to "Endpoints"
3. Look at the bottom of the page: find the CURL section and click on the eye

As you can see, the correct format is:
`curl -u xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -X POST https://us-south.functions.cloud.ibm.com/api/****************`